# print 2D array and print * for odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqgcO.png)
why does the console print my 2D array in a row?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; people need to be able to copy & paste your code and try it. See [ask]. Make sure you include that `display` method, we don't know what that is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `System.out.print` which doesn't append a newline to the end of your output, meaning it will just keep printing everything to the same line.

You can add the line `System.out.println()` inside your top-level loop, but after your inner loop, and it will log each 2nd-level array to it's own line.

Comment: As Robert mentioned, screenshots aren't ideal, because it means i can't copy and paste your code. If you amend your question to include a code snippet, I can include in my answer a corrected version of your code.